# MS-Access SQL - how to implement a boolean sub-query?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a membership database, with linked tables: `members` and `history`, where the `history` includes any update about the member, including joining date and leaving date in relevant cases.

**This means that within the `history` table there may be a few different records related to a member ID**.

I'd like to create a query that would result in a spreadsheet showing a member id, name and also the Membership Status - which will be "ON" as long as that member doesn't have a "leave" action in the `history` table (let's say number 3). It may have different actions, and in different order in the `history` table (so "leave" is not necessarily the last action).

Thus, the status displayed should be "OFF" if a "leave"(3) record is found related to that member among all records related to that member in `history`. Otherwise, it's "ON".

I tried something like the following, but it doesn't work, as the Exists part always returns true:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
Members.ID, 
Members.MemberName AS Name,
IIF(
 EXISTS(
  SELECT DISTINCT *
   FROM Members LEFT JOIN History ON Members.ID = History.MemberID
   WHERE (History.UpdateType <> 3)
  ),"ON", "OFF"
)
AS Status
FROM Members
ORDER BY Members.ID;
```

Thank you for any advice...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to correlate the subquery with the outer query. Also, I if followed you correctly, you want to check if *any* related history record has type = 3, and set the status to `'OFF'` in this case.

```
SELECT 
    Members.ID, 
    Members.MemberName AS Name,
    IIF(
        EXISTS(
            SELECT 1
            FROM History 
            WHERE (Members.ID = History.MemberID AND History.UpdateType = 3)
        ),
        'OFF', 
        'ON'
    ) AS Status
FROM Members
ORDER BY Members.ID;
```

Side note: you don't need `DISTINCT` in an `EXISTS` subquery (it is there to check if *anything* is there); likely, you don't need it in the outer query either.